# Java Compiler Object Code (Byte Code?)

Tags: java, c, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

A typical C program would be compiled, assembled, linked and loaded. I know that Java works with the JVM and produces byte code. Would it be possible to connect both "object files" using the linker? For example, a C program and a C++ program can be used together by playing with the linker and linking both object files.

Can the same be done between C and Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly link compiled C code with compiled Java code.

You can call compiled C or C++ code from Java using [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/):

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) enables the integration of code written in the Java programming language with code written in other languages such as C and C++. It allows programmers to take full advantage of the Java platform without having to abandon their investment in legacy code.

Answer (score 3):

This might be possible if you compile the C code to JVM bytecode, not to native code, so you would 'link' at the JVM level, not via a native object linker.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#C_to_bytecode_compilers

Comment: Blog post with a couple of implementations: http://depth-first.com/articles/2006/10/16/compiling-c-to-java-bytecode/

Comment: Of course, C translated to bytecodes is not really C -- many legal things in C are not legal in Java bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, at least not with any common tools.  The "object file" that `javac` produces is (informally) called "bytecode" and is a hardware-independent representation of a program for a stack machine (not much different from that used for old ["P-Code"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine) systems).

There are various tools that can translate Java bytecodes into executables for various hardware architectures, but all rather specialized -- none that I know of that produce linkable modules.

Answer (score 2):

GCC can compile Java to class files and then to executable assembler code [using `gcj`](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)

AFAIK, it's not useful to combine Java and C directly but the machine code must eventually be in a form that the normal linker can understand. You will probably need some assembler glue code to call between the two.